# Where should I place the NOTICE file and the license?

Tags: apache-2.0, license-notice

I want to create a project that's based on apache 2.0 open source code.
I know that I should include a NOTICE file and the license, but my question is where should I place them? in the code or inside the built application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place it in the root directory of your project.

Comment: is it fine to place it in the code itself? in a comment (both license and notice)?

Comment: If your project is a single file, put everything in that file. If your project is multiple files, don't put any comment at the top of the files. Just use the LICENSE and NOTICE files.

Comment: thanks I got it. but I still don't understand why its necessary nobody is going to see it